# Is it possible to conduct a POST on a server without rebooting it

Tags: reboot

Is it possible to do a Power On Self Test on a server without rebooting it?

I was told the it was possible but have not been able to find any further information on this topic. Is there additional software needed?

Comment: POST stands for "power on self test" and is something that is part of the motherboard boot sequence. The way a POST is executed is different depending on the device. What exactly are you trying to test for?

Comment: Who told you that you can POST a system without a reboot? Why didn’t you ask them about the details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible. The [POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test) is a function of the BIOS and only performed during boot-up. To access it, the system *must* be rebooted. After all, it is called the **Power-On** Self-Test. There is no way to access or run the testing code while booted in an operating system. Even if it were somehow possible, it would likely crash the operating system due to the nature of the tests.